# If a dataframe contains a value in a column, how to perform a calculation in another column? - Pandas/ Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculation

Original Dataframe:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1500 | 0 |

Output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1500 | 1.2 |

Logic needed: If column A contains 123, then for column C, take the value of B and multiply it with 0.0008, all the other values in column C should not be altered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if column "A" values are 123 or not and use `mask` on "C" to replace values there:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df['A']==123, df['B']*0.0008)
```

Output:

```
     A     B    C
0  123  1500  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want to check if dataframe['A'] contains 123, if yes it should multiply the column B value with 0.0008 and append it in column C. If that's the case here's how you should go with it:

```
#Considering your dataframe is a pandas dataframe stored in variable 'df'
vals_a = df.index[df['A'] == 123].tolist () #Returns the list of the indexes containing 123.
for b in vals_a:
   val_b = df['B'].values[b]
   df.loc[val_b,'C'] = df.loc[b, 'B']*0.0008
```

This basically replaces the same index value in column 'C' with the mupltiplication of 0.0008 with the value in column B if column A includes 123.